# URLスキームで起動した Xamarin アプリからブラウザの元の画面に戻る方法について

Tags: xamarin

URLスキームで起動した Xamarin アプリからブラウザの元の画面に戻る方法について、特に iOS での実装方法について質問させてください。

以下のような Xamarin のアプリとブラウザの連携を考えています。

1. ブラウザからXamarin アプリを呼出す。
2. Xamarin アプリでの処理の後、元のブラウザ画面に戻る。

1.については、Xamarin アプリの呼出しについては、カスタム URL スキームを使い、JavaScript で以下のようにすることで Android・iOS とも呼び出せることは確認できています。

```
location.href = myapp://XXXX;
```

2.については、新しい画面を開くのでなく元の画面に戻りたいため、Browser.OpenAsync() は使えないと思っています。このような場合、どのような実装を行えばいいのでしょうか？

Android の場合、Activity.Finish() を使うことでやりたいことは実現できました。
iOS の場合、どのようにすれば実現できるでしょうか？